# Как правильно: своем или его?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, выбор-слов, местоимения

> Иванов понимал, что встреча с Петровым была одной из важнейших милостей Всевышнего на своем жизненном пути.

По-моему, вместо СВОЕМ должно быть ЕГО. Так ли это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, здесь должно быть "его". Дело в том, что в придаточном предложении другой производитель действия (встреча), поэтому "свой" нельзя отнести к Иванову. А чтобы "его" не относилось к Всевышнему или к Петрову, лучше изменить порядок слов (либо можно добавить уточнение: "его, Иванова,"):

> Иванов понимал, что на **его** жизненном пути встреча с Петровым была
>   одной из важнейших милостей Всевышнего.

Предложение со словом "свой"  может быть таким:

> Иванов понимал, что нельзя ему было на **своём** жизненном пути забыть
>   столь важную милость Всевышнего, как встреча с Петровым.

Или таким:

> Иванов припомнил на **своём** жизненном пути столь важную милость
>   Всевышнего, как встреча с Петровым.